# Azure REST API to get list of PaaS and SaaS services

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

Does Azure provide any Management REST APIs to fetch the list of PaaS and SaaS services used by a Azure Account or Subscription.

For e.g. If my Account is using Multifactor Auth, Advisor Services, AD etc I need to get that list of services in a REST API call

I am unable to find these APIs in the below Resource Management API list
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: is there any update on my answer ? If you find my answer is helpful please accept/upvote it. so that it can help other community members

Comment: was waiting for more helpful answers, you're answer doesn't help me, i already know about the RMM APIs

Answer (score -1):

There is no option to get the list of the **PaaS and SaaS** Service alone using the API.

However, you can get all the resources under a particular `Subscriptionid` and `filter` using it's `type` using [Azure List Resouce API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list)

1st You should find your Paas/Saas Resouce type, for an instance, say it's is `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories`

```
    var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal("<Clientid>", "<ClientSecret?", "<TenantId>",AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
    var resouceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = "<SubID>" };
    var resource = resouceManagementClient.Resources.ListAsync(new ODataQuery<GenericResourceFilterInner>(x => x.ResourceType == "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories")).Result;
```

Like that you can add many filters to get that particular resource types.

Comment: I am already using RMM API, hope MS comes with  API for PaaS and Saas service

Comment: As mentioned in my answer there is no API option currently available for Paas and Saas service. You can provide your own [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) in order to get notify the MS Azure Team

Comment: Thanks, I have added a suggestion here, please vote for it if you agree https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/35606941-management-api-for-paas-saas-sevices